# posting two key-value pair in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurlconnection

I am trying to post login information on the server using `POST` in `NSURLCconnection`. I have to set two key-value pair as `emailIdSignIn:abc@def.com` and `passwordSignIn:xxxxxxx`. But the problem is, i am getting only `emailIdSignIn` value on server and value of `passwordSignIn` appended in `emailIdSignIn` field, and `passwordSignIn` is nil. I have tried `NSDictionary` as well but getting `null` in both field in that case. I can't change the server side code. Here is my code for 
**client side**

```
 /* initiating request with the url */
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2:8080/referamaid/app/noauth/serviceconsumer/login"]];

    NSString *loginData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"emailIdSignIn=%@,passwordSignIn=%@",[self.emailTextField text],[self.passwordTextField text],nil];

    NSLog(@"login data = %@", loginData);


    NSData *postData = [loginData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];

    /* specify the request type */

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    /* set the data to be posted on server into body for "POST"*/

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"posted data = %@", postData);

    /* inititate connection between app and server*/

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [connection start];
    if(!connection)
    {
        // Release the receivedData object.

        receivedData = nil;

        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }
}
}
```

**server side code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "noauth/serviceconsumer/login"  , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String noAuthScLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String retVal = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");

        String emailId = request.getParameter("emailIdSignIn");
        String password = request.getParameter("passwordSignIn");
}
}
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"login data = %@", loginData);` print right data? And can you show the dictionary code that you tried?

Comment: here is the login data = emailIdSignIn=k@k.com,passwordSignIn=12345678

Comment: Why you're not using AFNetworking library where you can simply create a NSDictionary with your params and pass it to .POST method?

Comment: I am using NSDictionary to hold data, then NSDictionary -> JSON -> POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)):

> When a web browser sends a POST request from a web form element, the
>   default Internet media type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".[8]
>   This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate
>   keys. Each key-value pair is separated by an '&' character, and each
>   key is separated from its value by an '=' character. Keys and values
>   are both escaped by replacing spaces with the '+' character and then
>   using URL encoding on all other non-alphanumeric[9] characters.

So you need to use `&` character instead of `,`:

```
NSString *loginData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"emailIdSignIn=%@&passwordSignIn=%@",[self.emailTextField text],[self.passwordTextField text]];
```